# Components don't render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have axios get method which is called from Mobx store here's the code:

`fetchPizzas=()=>{axios.get("http://localhost:3000/db.json").then((resp)=>{this.setPizzas(resp.data.pizzas);})}`

In App.js i call this method with React useEffect like this:
`React.useEffect(()=>pizzaStore.fetchPizzas(), []);`
However, all the pizza items don't render unless you click any button on the page. I am replacing jsx files with tsx files if that matters.

Comment: Add a complete code of your component. And also since you are have useEffect it looks like you are using functional component. You should not be using `this.setPizzas` it should be just `setPizzas` remove the `this` .

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all relevant code for what you are trying to do. We should see what you are trying to render and how.

Comment: How do you ' add ' the pizza items to your component ? Are you adding them on component state ? or from redux store ? can you please show that ?

Comment: You'll also have to show how you're displaying data. This is just fetching. So what I think, you're updating state in the function with axios and returning that state data to `App.js` ? That state update takes some time and by that time your App have already rendered and there is no data to show. But when you click button, it re-renders and finds the data there to display.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the state of pizzaStore  in your react.useEffect
as fetchPizzas is saving the state this.setPizzas and the 'this' context looks like pizzaStore,

I think once pizzaStore is updated, you should update the state of App so it re-renders.

is pizzaStore saved as state of App, in which case you may want something like:

```
componentDidMount(){
    pizzaStore.fetchPizzas();
}  


// runs when pizzaStore is updated.
React.useEffect(()=> {
    setPizzaStore(pizzaStore)
, [pizzaStore]);
```